# How to add rows based on a condition with another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, append

I have two dataframes as follows:

agreement

```
  agreement_id activation  term_months  total_fee
0            A 2020-12-01           24       4800
1            B 2021-01-02            6        300
2            C 2021-01-21            6        600
3            D 2021-03-04            6        300
```

payments

```
    cust_id agreement_id       date  payment
0         1            A 2020-12-01      200
1         1            A 2021-02-02      200
2         1            A 2021-02-03      100
3         1            A 2021-05-01      200
4         1            B 2021-01-02       50
5         1            B 2021-01-09       20
6         1            B 2021-03-01       80
7         1            B 2021-04-23       90
8         2            C 2021-01-21      600
9         3            D 2021-03-04      150
10        3            D 2021-05-03      150
```

I want to add another row in the payments dataframe when the total payments for the agreement_id  in the payments dataframe is equal to the total_fee in the agreement_id. The row would contain a zero value under the payments and the date will be calculated as min(date) (from payments) plus term_months (from agreement).

Here's the results I want for the payments dataframe:

payments

```
    cust_id agreement_id       date  payment
0         1            A 2020-12-01      200
1         1            A 2021-02-02      200
2         1            A 2021-02-03      100
3         1            A 2021-05-01      200
4         1            B 2021-01-02       50
5         1            B 2021-01-09       20
6         1            B 2021-03-01       80
7         1            B 2021-04-23       90
8         2            C 2021-01-21      600
9         3            D 2021-03-04      150
10        3            D 2021-05-03      150
11        2            C 2021-07-21      0
12        3            D 2021-09-04      0
```

The additional rows are row 11 and 12. The agreement_id 'C' and 'D' where equal to the total_fee shown in the agreement dataframe.

Comment: Can you show your code of your attempt to tackle this? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to convert `date` to `datetime` format with `pd.to_datetime()` (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)) in order to create new datetime values — unless you want to do it manually.

Comment: I converted it just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Firstly convert 'date' column of payment dataframe into datetime dtype by using `to_datetime()` method:

```
payments['date']=pd.to_datetime(payments['date'])
```

You can do this by using `groupby()` method:

```
newdf=payments.groupby('agreement_id').agg({'payment':'sum','date':'min','cust_id':'first'}).reset_index()
```

Now by boolean masking get the data which mets your condition:

```
newdf=newdf[agreement['total_fee']==newdf['payment']].assign(payment=np.nan)
```

**Note:** here in the above code we are using `assign()` method and making the payments row to `NaN`

Now make use of `pd.tseries.offsets.Dateoffsets()` method and `apply()` method:

```
newdf['date']=newdf['date']+agreement['term_months'].apply(lambda x:pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=x))
```

**Note:** The above code gives you a warning so just ignore that warning as it's a warning not an error

Finally make use of `concat()` method and `fillna()` method:

```
result=pd.concat((payments,newdf),ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output

```
#output

   cust_id  agreement_id    date    payment
0   1           A       2020-12-01  200.0
1   1           A       2021-02-02  200.0
2   1           A       2021-02-03  100.0
3   1           A       2021-05-01  200.0
4   1           B       2021-01-02  50.0
5   1           B       2021-01-09  20.0
6   1           B       2021-03-01  80.0
7   1           B       2021-04-23  90.0
8   2           C       2021-01-21  600.0
9   3           D       2021-03-04  150.0
10  3           D       2021-05-03  150.0
11  2           C       2021-07-21  0.0
12  3           D       2021-09-04  0.0
```

**Note:** If you want exact same output then make use of `astype()` method and change payment column dtype from `float` to `int`

```
result['payment']=result['payment'].astype(int)
```

Comment: I had a typo in row 11 and row 12 because i inputted 150 instead of 0 for the values under the payment. Anyways, I just replaced result=pd.concat((payments,newdf),ignore_index=True).ffill() with result = pd.concat([payments,newdf], axis=0).fillna(0)

Comment: ohh...ok...Updated this in the answer **:)**